# Calculation of an integral with exponential and logarithmic functions

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to do the following integral
$$I = \int_{x}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} k^{\frac{2}{c}\ln u} \left(c \ln \left(\frac{k}{u}\right) - 2 c + 2 \ln^2 \left(\frac{k}{u}\right)\right) \exp \left\{-\frac{ \left[c^2 + 4 \ln^2 \left(ku\right)\right]}{8 c}\right\} {\kern 1pt} \,du}$$
where $k > 0$ and $c > 0$ are some constants.

Upon completing the square in the power of $e$.
$$I = \sqrt{k}\int_{x}^{\infty}{k^{\frac{2}{c}\ln u} \left(c \ln \left(\frac{k}{u}\right) - 2 c + 2 \ln^2 \left(\frac{k}{u}\right)\right) \exp \left\{-\frac{ \left[c + 2 \ln \left(ku\right)\right]^2}{8 c}\right\} {\kern 1pt} \,du}$$

Let $\ln u = v$. Then the integral becomes
$$I = \sqrt{k}\int_{x}^{\infty}{k^{\large \frac{2v}{c}} \left(c \ln k - cv - 2 c + 2 \left(\ln k - v\right) ^2 \right) \exp \left\{v -\frac{ \left[c + 2 \ln \left(k\right) + 2v\right]^2}{8 c}\right\} {\kern 1pt} \,dv}$$
I am not sure how to proceed from here. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is x a constant as well?

Comment: @mikevandernaald, it is a variable from the other part of my equation, but as far as the integral is concerned it can be treated as a constant, no ?

Comment: There are _three_ integrals? I only see one, the integral over $u$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidZ, There is only one integral over u, but there is an additive part with three functions, right in the middle of the integrand, which can be used to rewrite the integral into 3 integrals, all over u with the same limits, that's what I was referring to, apologies if that is misleading.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Yeah, I'd say it's a little misleading, but not serious enough to make it worth editing the question unless you're also fixing other stuff.

Comment: @DavidZ, I have revised the post.